# Spring Boot Web Application using Thymeleaf, Search bar not working

Tags: html, spring-boot, search, spring-data, spring-thymeleaf

I have a user table in a file called list-users. On this page there is also a search bar where you can search for users but it always returns an empty table instead of one containing the user.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>User Directory</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h3>User Directory</h3>
    <hr>
    <!-- Add a button -->

    <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for a user" id="searchInput">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="searchButton">Search</button>
    </div>

    <a th:href="@{/users/AddUser}"
       class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3">
        Add User
    </a>

    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead class="table-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Zeus Prayer Points</th>
            <th>Poseidon Prayer Points</th>
            <th>Hades Prayer Points</th>
            <th>Aphrodite Prayer Points</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="tempUser : ${users}">

            <td th:text="${tempUser.userName}" />
            <td th:text="${tempUser.ZeusPP}" />
            <td th:text="${tempUser.PoseidonPP}" />
            <td th:text="${tempUser.HadesPP}" />
            <td th:text="${tempUser.AphroditePP}" />
            <!-- Add update button link -->
            <td>
                <a th:href="@{/users/UpdateUser(userId=${tempUser.id})}"
                   class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                    Update
                </a>

                <!--Add delete button-->
                <a th:href="@{/users/delete(userId=${tempUser.id})}"
                   class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                   onclick="if (!(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?'))) return false">
                    Delete

                </a>

                <!-- Add sacrifice button-->
                <a th:href="@{/users/sacrifice(userId=${tempUser.id})}"
                   class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                    Sacrifice
                </a>

                <!-- Add prayer button -->
                <a th:href="@{/users/prayer(userId=${tempUser.id})}"
                   class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                    Pray
                </a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        const searchButton = document.querySelector('#searchButton');
        const searchInput = document.querySelector('#searchInput');
        searchButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const searchText = searchInput.value.trim();
            if (searchText !== '') {
                fetch(`/users/search?searchText=${searchText}`)
                    .then(response => response.text())
                    .then(html => {
                        const tableBody = document.querySelector('tbody');
                        tableBody.innerHTML = html;
                    });
            }
        });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the list-user.html,

```
package com.ggs.at9.controller;

import com.ggs.at9.entity.User;
import com.ggs.at9.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;



import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    private UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService theUserService){
        userService = theUserService;
    }

    //add mapping for main page

    @GetMapping("/main")
    public String listUsers(Model theModel){
        //get users from db
        List<User> theUsers = userService.findAll();
        //add to spring model
        theModel.addAttribute("users", theUsers);

        return "users/list-users";
    }

    @GetMapping("/AddUser")
    public String addUser(Model theModel){
        User theUser = new User();

        theModel.addAttribute("user", theUser);

        return "users/users-form";
    }

    @GetMapping("/UpdateUser")
    public String updateUser(@RequestParam("userId") int theId, Model theModel){
        //get the user from the service
        User theUser = userService.findById(theId);
        //set user in the model to prepopulate the form
        theModel.addAttribute("user", theUser);
        //send this over to our form

        return "users/users-form";
    }

    @GetMapping("/sacrifice")
    public String userSacrifice(@RequestParam("userId") int theId, Model theModel){
        //get the user from the service
        User theUser = userService.findById(theId);
        //put the user in the model
        theModel.addAttribute("user", theUser);
        //send the user to the sacrifice page
        return "users/sacrifice-form";
    }

    @GetMapping("/prayer")
    public String userPrayer(@RequestParam("userId") int theId, Model theModel){
        //get the user from the service
        User theUser = userService.findById(theId);
        //put the user in the model
        theModel.addAttribute("user", theUser);
        //send the user to the sacrifice page
        return "users/prayer-form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User theUser){
        //save the user
        userService.save(theUser);

        //use redirect to prevent duplicate submissions
        return"redirect:/users/main";
    }

    @GetMapping("/delete")
    public String delete(@RequestParam("userId") int theId){
        //delete user
        userService.deleteById(theId);
        //redirect to the users list
        return "redirect:/users/main";

    }

    @GetMapping("/search")
    public String searchUsers(@RequestParam("searchText") String searchText, Model model) {
        List<User> matchingUsers = userService.findByUserNameContaining(searchText);
        logger.info("Search query returned {} results for search text: {}", matchingUsers.size(), searchText);
        logger.info("Matching users: {}", matchingUsers.stream().map(User::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
        model.addAttribute("users", matchingUsers);
        return "/users/list-users :: tableBody";
    }


    @PostMapping("/thunderPig")
    public String addToZeusPP(@RequestParam("userId") int theId, Model theModel){
        System.out.print("The value of theId is: {}" + theId);;
        userService.addToZeusPP(theId);
        return "redirect:/users/main";
    }

    @PostMapping("/fish")
    public String addToPoseidonPP(@RequestParam("userId") int theId, Model theModel){
        System.out.print("The value of theId is: {}" + theId);;
        userService.addToPoseidonPP(theId);
        return "redirect:/users/main";
    }

    @PostMapping("/cockroach")
    public String addToHadesPP(@RequestParam("userId") int theId, Model theModel){
        System.out.print("The value of theId is: {}" + theId);;
        userService.addToHadesPP(theId);
        return "redirect:/users/main";
    }

    @PostMapping("/flower")
    public String addToAphroditePP(@RequestParam("userId") int theId, Model theModel) {
        System.out.print("The value of theId is: {}" + theId);
        ;
        userService.addToAphroditePP(theId);
        return "redirect:/users/main";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/blessing")
    public String blessing(@RequestParam("userId") int theId, Model theModel){
        return "redirect:/users/main";
    }
    
    
}
```

This is my Controller class

```
package com.ggs.at9.service;

import com.ggs.at9.dao.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import com.ggs.at9.entity.User;


@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository theUserRepository){ userRepository = theUserRepository;}

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() { return userRepository.findAll();}

    @Override
    public User findById(int theId) {
        Optional<User> result = userRepository.findById(theId);

        User theUser = null;

        if (result.isPresent()) {
            theUser = result.get();
        }
        else {
            // we didn't find the User
            throw new RuntimeException("Did not find user id - " + theId);
        }

        return theUser;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(User theUser) {
        userRepository.save(theUser);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(int theId) {
        userRepository.deleteById(theId);
    }

    @Override
    public void addToZeusPP(int theId) {

        System.out.println("User id: " + theId); // Print the value of theId to the console

        Optional<User> result = userRepository.findById(theId);
        if (result.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println("User id: " + theId); // Print the value of theId to the console

            User user = result.get();
            int currentZeusPP = user.getZeusPP();
            user.setZeusPP(currentZeusPP + 1);
            userRepository.save(user);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Did not find user id - " + theId);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void addToPoseidonPP(int theId) {

        System.out.println("User id: " + theId); // Print the value of theId to the console

        Optional<User> result = userRepository.findById(theId);
        if (result.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println("User id: " + theId); // Print the value of theId to the console

            User user = result.get();
            int currentPoseidonPP = user.getPoseidonPP();
            user.setPoseidonPP(currentPoseidonPP + 1);
            userRepository.save(user);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Did not find user id - " + theId);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void addToHadesPP(int theId) {


        Optional<User> result = userRepository.findById(theId);
        if (result.isPresent()) {

            User user = result.get();
            int currentHadesPP = user.getHadesPP();
            user.setHadesPP(currentHadesPP + 1);
            userRepository.save(user);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Did not find user id - " + theId);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void addToAphroditePP(int theId) {

        System.out.println("User id: " + theId); // Print the value of theId to the console

        Optional<User> result = userRepository.findById(theId);
        if (result.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println("User id: " + theId); // Print the value of theId to the console

            User user = result.get();
            int currentAphroditePP = user.getAphroditePP();
            user.setAphroditePP(currentAphroditePP + 1);
            userRepository.save(user);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Did not find user id - " + theId);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findByUserNameContaining(String searchText) {
        return userRepository.findByUserNameContaining(searchText);
    }


}
```

This is my Service Implementation class

```
package com.ggs.at9.dao;

import com.ggs.at9.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    List<User> findByUserNameContaining(String searchText);

   

}
```

This is my Repository interface

```
package com.ggs.at9.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    //define fields

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="ZeusPP")
    private int ZeusPP;

    @Column(name="PoseidonPP")
    private int PoseidonPP;

    @Column(name="HadesPP")
    private int HadesPP;

    @Column(name="AphroditePP")
    private int AphroditePP;

    //define contructors

    public User(){}

    public User(int id, String userName, int ZeusPP, int PoseidonPP, int HadesPP, int AphroditePP){
        this.id =  id;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.ZeusPP =  ZeusPP;
        this.PoseidonPP =  PoseidonPP;
        this.HadesPP =  HadesPP;
        this.AphroditePP =  AphroditePP;
    }

    public User(String userName, int zeusPP, int poseidonPP, int hadesPP, int aphroditePP) {
        this.userName = userName;
        ZeusPP = zeusPP;
        PoseidonPP = poseidonPP;
        HadesPP = hadesPP;
        AphroditePP = aphroditePP;
    }

    //define getters/setters


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public int getZeusPP() {
        return ZeusPP;
    }

    public void setZeusPP(int zeusPP) {
        ZeusPP = zeusPP;
    }

    public int getPoseidonPP() {
        return PoseidonPP;
    }

    public void setPoseidonPP(int poseidonPP) {
        PoseidonPP = poseidonPP;
    }

    public int getHadesPP() {
        return HadesPP;
    }

    public void setHadesPP(int hadesPP) {
        HadesPP = hadesPP;
    }

    public int getAphroditePP() {
        return AphroditePP;
    }

    public void setAphroditePP(int aphroditePP) {
        AphroditePP = aphroditePP;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", userName='" + userName + '\'' +
                ", ZeusPP=" + ZeusPP +
                ", PoseidonPP=" + PoseidonPP +
                ", HadesPP=" + HadesPP +
                ", AphroditePP=" + AphroditePP +
                '}';
    }
}
```

This is my UserClass

If someone could show me why the search bar isn't working i would really appreciate it.